# Showing correct error validation when logging in

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I am currently working on a school database. I am creating a login page using ASP.NET which is connected to my SQL Database (SQL Server Management Studio 2017). Currently I am able to successfully connect my username and password as well as its person type which are all attributes in my Person Table in my SQL Database when I log in. However, my problem is, I'm not able to show correct validation when I use an incorrect "Person Type". To make this clear, I have a drop down list in my login page that shows the different user type there is such as Students, Teacher, Admin, Principal, Parents, etc.

This is the code for this,

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" 

Inherits="LoginQuery.Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #login-div {
            position: absolute;
            left: 40%;
            top: 40%;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 10px 10px;
        }
       /* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
        .topnav {
            background-color: #333;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
        .topnav a {
            float: left;
            color: #f2f2f2;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
        }
        body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
        form {border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;}

        input[type=text], input[type=password] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        button {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            padding: 14px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 100%;
        }

        button:hover {
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        .cancelbtn {
            width: auto;
            padding: 10px 18px;
            background-color: #f44336;
        }

        .imgcontainer {
            text-align: center;
            margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
        }

        img.avatar {
            width: 40%;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

        .container {
            padding: 16px;
        }

        span.psw {
            float: right;
            padding-top: 16px;
        }

        /* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
        @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
            span.psw {
               display: block;
               float: none;
            }
            .cancelbtn {
               width: 100%;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="text-align:center" class="topnav">
            <h1 style="font-family:Verdana; color:white">Login</h1>
            <table id="login-div">
                <tr>
                    <td>Select User Type: </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Button1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="155px">
                        <asp:ListItem>Student</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Teacher</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Counselor</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Parent</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Principal</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Admin</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username: </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" placeholder="Enter Username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password: </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" placeholder="Enter password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="BtnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" BackColor="Gray" ForeColor="White" OnClick="BtnLogin_Click" />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="Red" Width="100%"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my Login.aspx.cs code. This is where I call the query when the login button is submitted. It basically checks in the SQL if the login credentials are there and if its valid, if not, it shows a error message using the label.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace LoginQuery
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=CHRIS\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FPSDD;Integrated Security=True";
            con.Open();
        }

        protected void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Person where Username='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "' and PersonType='" + DropDownList3.SelectedItem + "'";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(ds, "Person");
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                Response.Redirect(url: "http://localhost:56061/");
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Invalid User Type, Username or Password. Please Try Again!";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Overall, I want to be able to show correct validation if some enters a username and password thats not correlated to the correct user type. In that case, I want to tell the user that their credentials do not match the user type selected. Another is to show a correct validation for in correct username or password. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. If you need any more clarification, please do ask.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a different query for each case:

1. First check username, password, user type exists in the database, if yes then your login is successful.
2. If a 1st case is not satisfied then check username and password are exists, if yes then credentials are correct but its relevant user type is not proper.

Code should be as follows:

```
protected void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Person where Username='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "' and PersonType='" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue+ "'";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    sda.Fill(ds, "Person");
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect(url: "http://localhost:56061/");
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Person where Username='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(ds, "Person");

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Invalid User Type. Please Try Again!";
        }
        else
        {

            Label1.Text = "Invalid User Type, Username or Password. Please Try Again!";
        }
    }
}
```

Another way to do it. This solution will reduce one database call.

```
protected void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Person where Username='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    sda.Fill(ds, "Person");
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PersonType"] == DropDownList3.SelectedValue)
        {
            Response.Redirect(url: "http://localhost:56061/");
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Invalid User Type. Please Try Again!";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Invalid User Type, Username or Password. Please Try Again!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Try the second solution, it is the optimized one.

Comment: The second solution only seem to show the last label text when the user type is incorrect but with correct credentials.

Comment: Debug the code, it should display the `Invalid User Type. Please Try Again!` only if you get any ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count  is more than 0...

Comment: I debugged and it's still doing the same error. For entering correct credentials with incorrect user type, it shows the error, " Invalid User Type, Username or Password. Please Try Again!" instead of "Invalid User Type. Please Try Again!".

Comment: I have updated answer, change DropDownList3.SelectedItem to DropDownList3.SelectedValue

Comment: Add mentioned by Surjit SD, use the parameterized query to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query needs a modification

Instead of using `DropdownList.SelectedItem` you should use `SelectedValue`

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Person where Username='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "' and PersonType='" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue+ "'";
```

Also your code is vulnerable to
`SQL injection attack.` To avoid this use `@variables` instead of string concatenation.

**Example**

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Person where Username=@username and Password=@password";
```

And pass the variables to `SqlCommand` object.

Also, you are not using the * (all columns) mentioned in SQL query, so you can just bring back only `PersonType` instead of all columns, this will save you from fetching unnecessary data.

Last, but not least- you are using global class fields to store `Connection` and `Command`, you will run into some problem very soon. Try using `Connection` and `Command` objects only in the method that is calling database.

Also you need to do connection management, so use `using{}` block to make sure connection closes after database call.

**Example**

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringHere))
{
    var cmd = SqlCommand(query,conn);
     //other code
}
```